# Adding object to Set generically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to achieve the following

```
public void Add<T1, R> ( T1 entity, R virtualEntity )
        {
            entity.Set<R>().Add( virtualEntity );
        }
```

That is, given a `T1 entity` and a `R virtualEntity`, I want to be able to add that virtual entity to the `T1 entity`'s `DbSet`.

Of course, `T1 entity` has no Set method. Is there a way to do this?

For example, I have teacher - student relationship and I want to do

```
Teacher.Set<Student>().Add("John");
```

Of course, Teacher will have `Teacher.Students`, but I can't access that in a generic method. I need a generic way to access the virtual set of a given type.

Comment: Can't you use `DbContext.Set(typeof(T1)).Add()`?

Comment: How would a `Teacher` class have a `DbSet<Student>`? `DbSet`s belong to `DbContext`s. It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, and why.

Comment: Maybe it's not called that, I'm talking about the set that is returned when you state Teacher.Students, which you can call Add on.

Comment: Well, that's probably an `ICollection`, but even then it's absolutely unclear to me why you don't just do `teacher.Students.Add(newStudent)`. What do you gain by making this uber generic?

Comment: So I can change all the areas where I use it just by changing it in one place. Do you know of a possible way to fetch those ICollections?

Comment: How about using reflection? Or is that too slow?

Comment: In case you're interested, I found the solution. It was pretty easy in the end. Why didn't you come up with this?

Comment: Because this is not helpful at all, it even makes things harder. Compared to simply doing `teacher.Students.Add(student)` you've lost compile-time checking that `Students` actually is an `ICollection<Student>`. This is runtime errors waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
 public void Add<T1, R> ( T1 entity, R virtualEntity, string virtualStr )
        {
            var result = entity.GetType().GetProperty( virtualStr );
            var value = result.GetValue( entity ) as Collection<R>;
            if ( value != null ) value.Add( virtualEntity );
            else
            {
                result.SetValue( entity, new Collection<R>() );
                value = result.GetValue( entity ) as Collection<R>;
                value.Add( virtualEntity );
            }
        }
```

I use it like so:

```
Add(teacher, student, "Students");
```